# Code in CSS Files is on One Line?

Tags: css, formatting

I am collaborating with Senior Developers and quite embarrassed to ask why the code in all the `.css` files is on one line?! At first I thought it was minified but when I went to unminify it it said `Unrecognized format`. How do I work with these files? As far as I can see it's ONLY the `.css` files.

Comment: With no code to see to represent your issue it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Ask them, there is nothing to be embarrased about.

Comment: It's certainly minified - what tool were you using to un-minify it? Make sure you're using something that's designed for CSS, not Javascript. And if you want to ask without asking, ask "So where is the un-minified CSS source, and how / where are we minifying it?"

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask, it's the only way to learn :) Look up for other folders where the unminified file(s) is/are. It can be the case they are using a CSS compiler (like SASS or LESS), in that case the files won't have .css extension but .SASS, .SCSS, .LESS which will be compiled into a single CSS. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It can be the case they are using a CSS compiler (like SASS or LESS),
>   in that case the files won't have .css extension but .SASS, .SCSS,
>   .LESS which will be compiled into a single CSS. - Teknotica

Tecknotica's speculation was correct. So to be more specific this is how you would work with these files given a similar situation. You don't actually write CSS directly into the CSS file but instead add your CSS to a SCSS file that then gets compiled into the CSS file using a tool such as Grunt. The CSS is all on one line in the CSS file (the one you don't directly write to) apparently because it reduces to the number of requests to get the bits. Thanks for everyone's help & advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ew, that's annoying. Usually when I come across that, I just do a search and replace for " ; " and add a break beneath it to help organize everything. Hope that helps!